# How do I extract the source from a bokeh figure?

Tags: bokeh

I'm passing a Bokeh Figure instance as an input to another function and I need to modify its source there.
Can't figure out how to do it!

This is how I created the figure instance:

```py
source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [1,2,3], 'y': [2,4,6]})  

p = figure(tools='pan,wheel_zoom,save,reset', name='p', toolbar_location='above')  

p.circle('x', 'y', source=source, color='slategray', alpha=0.6, name='glyph')
```

The function that gets this figure should look like:

```py
def modify_source(fig):
    fig.source.data['x'] = [6,7,8]
    return fig
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `data_source` is a property of glyph renderer:

```
circle = p.circle('x', 'y', source=source, color='slategray', alpha=0.6, name='glyph')
print(circle.data_source)
```

And the JSON data that you passed to `ColumnDataSoource` can be accessed by:

```
print(circle.data_source.data)
```

In general for a given plot:

```
plot = figure()
line = plot.line('x', 'y', source = source)
circle = plot.circle('x', 'y', source = source)
for renderer in plot.renderers:
    if hasattr(renderer, 'glyph'):
        print (renderer.data_source.data)
```

So in your case you could do:

```
def modify_source(circle):
    circle.data_source.data['x'] = [6,7,8]
    circle.data_source.change.emit() # for changes to take effect
    return circle
```

Comment: `hasattr('glyph', renderer)` should be `hasattr(renderer, 'glyph')`